# Firebase Email/Password Authentication exception thrown only when attempting to retrieve task.getResult()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it just me that doesn't understand how `task.getResult()` is supposed to work?  Is it intended to return (or cause) an exception?  Is the reason for the vague failure message a security reason? Like to prevent people from probing for information about existing accounts?

Whilst trying to implement the Firebase Email/Password Authentication, I decided I would like to log/toast more than just `authorization failed` in the event that a user account creation and/or sign-in fails.

So I took the code below and replaced the assignment `temp = "poop"` with `temp = task.getResult().toString()`. This way, I can get better details when testing the app. But strangely, the app crashes when I call `temp = task.getResult().toString()`. It reports:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: [classified], PID: 24461
com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException: The email address is already in use by another account.
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzh.getResult(Unknown Source)... etc etc etc etc
```

**But it doesn't crash** as long as I don't call `task.getResult()`, even though the same condition happens (*trying to make a duplicate account*).

I would like to get the error in a toast, not in a stack trace. This code works and toasts `"poop"` when account creation fails:

```
 mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                        String temp =  "poop"; // task.getResult().toString();

                        Toast.makeText(Sign_IN_Activity.this, temp,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // Toast.makeText(Sign_IN_Activity.this, R.string.auth_failed,
                        //        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    else if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(Sign_IN_Activity.this, R.string.auth_succeeded,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
    // [END create_user_with_email]
}
```

This code crashes, putting `task.getResult()` in the stack trace instead of in the Toast:

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                        String temp =  task.getResult().toString();

                        Toast.makeText(Sign_IN_Activity.this, temp,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // Toast.makeText(Sign_IN_Activity.this, R.string.auth_failed,
                        //        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    else if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(Sign_IN_Activity.this, R.string.auth_succeeded,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
    // [END create_user_with_email]
}
```

I made a little workaround(?):

```
if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                        String temp = "auth failed";
                        try {
                            temp =  task.getException().getMessage();
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                        Toast.makeText(Sign_IN_Activity.this, temp,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "work around" is the right approach. The correct way to get a text string for test and debug logging is `task.getException().getMessage()`.  However, that string may not be suitable for use in a toast because, in SDK version 9.4.0, the message is always English.  It is not affected by the device locale.

Comment: You're a Jr. Frank van Puffelen

Comment: @AbAppletic: Thanks for the kind words.  I enjoy helping where I can.  I doubt anyone can match Frank's knowledge, generosity, _and_ patience.